# Specify groups of tests to run using "dotnet test"

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, tfsbuild, mstest, tfs-2015

I try to run specific tests using the "dotnet test" in a build step with TFS2015 (the test runner is mstest, using MVC Core framework).

In .net 4.5, I used to simply specify a parameter such as `"TestCategory=Unit"` in Test filter when building a Visual Studio Test step, in addition to adding an anotation like this `[TestCategory("Unit"), TestMethod()]` or `[TestCategory("Integration"), TestMethod()]` to each method.

Is there anyway to do something similar, using MStest or other framework?

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio Test](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/releases/m109/Tasks/VsTest/README.md) task supports indicating a path to Custom Test Adaptors. So you can still use Visual Studio Test task and specify your test adaptor in `Path to Custom Test Adaptors` item:

> **Path to Custom Test Adaptors** is the path to any custom or third-party
>   test adapters for the framework for which the tests are written.
>
> - Supports a wide range of test frameworks such as NUnit, xUnit, Mocha,    and Jasmine
> - Automatically searches subfolders.
> - Automatically scans any packages folder and installs and uses any    NuGet packages containing test adapters without prompting.
> - Example: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Fabrikam\packages

Comment: Thanks, finally, I ended up using Visual Studio Test, but I still can't trigger only test labelled with TestCategory="unit" when using the TestFilter parameter (this is also not recognized in the VisualStudio on my desktop when I'm running tests), si I ended up doing separated test projects for Unit tests and Integration tests.